# Getting "ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables. The first table has `Dno` which is a PK and acts as a FK in the second table and `Dname`.

The second table has a `eno`,`first_name` , `last_name` ,`salary` and Dno (here it's an FK).

Whenever I insert some values it always shows that error.

Comment: Which error? and share your query as well

Comment: share the insert statement

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete error message as well as the code you are using that is failing.

Comment: You're trying to create a `Dno` in the second table that doesn't exist in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are getting that exception because of inserting a record on tables both of which do not have right FK, PK.
Please check if you column can accept NULL values or not it also may cause this problem

Make sure you have the same id(s) for all the tables you want to get.

No more can be said without actually seeing the tables, so
Pls show us your query and table dump to be sure